# Docker : detach from command executed after container creation

Tags: node.js, shell, docker, npm

I have a dockerised nodejs app with the following in the `run.sh` file --

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -ti --rm -v $PWD:/app -p 8080:8080 foo
docker exec uod npm run gulp start-live
```

This starts my app and runs the gulp script. I've got "gulp" defined as a script in package.json. (old project so yes still using gulp :/)

Only problem is I am unable to detach from docker using ctrl+p+q

If I instead move the run command to the `Dockerfile` --

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "gulp", "start-live"]
```

This does the same thing but I am able to detach from the container after it runs.

What can I do differently in the run file to be able to run the command from there and also be able to detach?

Comment: "Move the command to the Dockerfile" is probably the right answer: it's The One Thing The Container Does, and you shouldn't generally need to `docker exec` just to start a container's main process.

Comment: Yeah makes sense but currently I need to change run configs based on environment. Find it much easier to do it in run.sh instead of Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

All I need to do was to tag the command at the end of docker run ...

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -ti --rm -v $PWD:/app -p 8080:8080 foo npm run gulp start-live
```